# parentViewController return null on IOS

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I am presenting a view controller modally using this code :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    SubmitAYoNViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubmitAYoN"];
    [ivc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:ivc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then in my SubmitAYoNViewController I have this:

```
  NSLog(@"%@",self.parentViewController);
    if([self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[YesOrNoViewController class]]) {
        NSLog(@"do something");
}
```

self.parentVeiwController is NULL. Why is that?

EDIT : I want to access a method from my parent view controller, then one that the SubmitAYoN was opened from.

SOLUTION : I used delegates instead. As per answers below, the presentViewController does not create a parent-child relationship.

Comment: you checked your identifier in story board ? is it @"SubmitAYoN"?

Comment: @iDev Yes, identifiers are correct because the new view opens correctly and everything else seems to be working in that vc.

Comment: If you want the presenting view controller, then use `self.presentingViewController`. `self.parentViewController` returns the controllers parent which will be nil when it is not a child of another controller.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel isn't it a child if I open it using the presentViewController?

Comment: @ghostrider. From the documentation for `presentViewController`: "This method sets the presentedViewController property to the specified view controller, resizes that view controller's view based on the presentation style and then adds the view to the view hierarchy." So no mention of the controller being made a child as its the view that is added to the existing view hierarchy. So I am pretty sure you need to use `self.presentingViewController`.

Comment: From the documentation for `parentViewController` you were right up to iOS5: "Prior to iOS 5.0, if a view did not have a parent view controller and was being presented, the presenting view controller would be returned. On iOS 5, this behavior no longer occurs. Instead, use the presentingViewController property to access the presenting view controller. "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the presenting view controller, then use `self.presentingViewController`. `self.parentViewController` returns the controllers parent which will be nil when it is not a child of another controller.

So use:

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.presentingViewController);
if([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[YesOrNoViewController class]]) {
   NSLog(@"do something");
}
```

From the documentation for `presentViewController:`

> This method sets the `presentedViewController` property to the specified
>   view controller, resizes that view controller's view based on the
>   presentation style and then adds the view to the view hierarchy.

So no mention of the controller being made a child as it is the view that is added to the existing view hierarchy.

You would have been ok prior to iOS5. The documention for property `parentViewController` states:

> Prior to iOS 5.0, if a view did not have a parent view controller and
>   was being presented, the presenting view controller would be returned.
>   On iOS 5, this behavior no longer occurs. Instead, use the
>   `presentingViewController` property to access the presenting view
>   controller.

Answer (score 0):

`self.parentViewController` is something you presented from this `viewcontroller` or `self.navigationgtionController`

So when you are presenting a `viewcontroller` where you hold an instance of the `viewcontroller' will have self.parentViewController.